# How can I add SQL Server Database in my project setup

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, project, installation

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with C# and I am making a project. I used SQL Server Database in my project but I cant finish. I can't setup (exe). How can I add SQL server in my project setup? I can't find any video or article

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

You can search on [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms162169.aspx).

You need to create a project like DBConfig or something and you need to add that project in your setup. In your DbConfig project you can use SMO concepts to read the database, tables, execute the query etc.

Hope this will help.